# What is the sample size formula which i could possibly get minimum value in-vivo studies?

Tags: sample-size, sample

I am an undergraduate students who is struggling on how to do in vivo studies with my low budget. Therefore, I ask some help of you just in case you know about what sample size formula that I could use for my in vivo studies' sample size. I recently use slovin's formula. Is this right for in vivo studies? Or is it right for in vitro?

In my research, I have 3 kinds of sample: a. Meniscus b. Artificial Meniscus c. PLA-PCL-PMMA-Collagen Meniscus.

Thank you in advance.

Additional information:

[what you want to measure?]
negative control:

- a. rat's meniscus

positive control:

- a. artificial's meniscus
- b. pla-pcl-pmma-colagen meniscus

[what you want to compare?]
in vivo studies - the number of inflammatory infiltrate: macrophages and neutrophils between samples

[would a paired design be possible?]
Yes

Comment: I'm not sure that looking for the formula that gives the smallest sample size is the best approach. Sometimes in research, the budget will limit the sample size. Doing a [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)) analysis may help you estimate if it's likely that you observe an outcome if the effect is present.

Comment: Welcome to cross-validated. I'm afraid the question doesn't yet have sufficient information for us to answer it. At the very least, we'd need to know what you want to measure and what you want to compare. Also, would a paired design be possible?

Comment: @cbeleites ive added additional informations that youve asked for :) Thank you

Comment: @Ertxiem thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to plan the sample size for your study, you need to have some familiarity with the kinds of measurements you will be making: perhaps from your own prior work, perhaps from results of the work of others.

Specifically, you need to have some idea of the variability of the measurements and some idea about the size of difference that would give an interesting result.

With no idea about your potential data and your objectives, all I can do is to give an example for you to ponder. Then maybe you can refine your question.

Suppose you have $n$ rats, and you have two types of 'meniscus' measurements on each rat (giving 'paired data'). You find the difference $D_i$ in the two types of meniscus measurements on each rat, $i = 1,2, \dots, n.$ Then suppose that the differences are roughly normal and that the standard deviation of the $D_i$s
is about $10.$

If the size of difference you want to be able to detect is 10 or more, then about a dozen rats will be enough to give a probability of about $0.8$ or $0.9$ ('power') of success in detecting such a difference. This is assuming you do a paired t test at the 5% level of significance.

[The answer is the same if the standard deviation and the size of an important difference are both about 100---or both about 0.1.]

Here is output from Minitab statistical software:

```
 Power and Sample Size 

 Paired t Test

 Testing mean paired difference = 0 (versus > 0)
 Calculating power for mean paired difference = difference
 α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation of paired differences = 10

            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
        10       8    0.80      0.815019
        10      11    0.90      0.924489
        10      13    0.95      0.959703
```

[image]

By contrast, if you need to detect a real difference that is about half the size of the standard deviation of the differences, then you will need to use about three dozen rats.

```
            Sample  Target
Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         5      27    0.80      0.811832
         5      36    0.90      0.902575
         5      45    0.95      0.951240
```